# Apache Spark Driver doesn't see external jar

Tags: java, mysql, linux, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I'm getting this error:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

When I try to save something to MySQL database from the driver. From slaves I don't have this problem because I added `SparkConf.setJars`. I tried to add `JavaSparkContext.addJar`, parameter `spark.driver.extraLibraryPath` from code and file `spark-defaults.conf` and also parameter `--jars` during submitting application. These actions have not solved my problem, I would be very appreciated for any ideas or tips.

Comment: I also set the CLASSPATH variable on the driver machine and it doesn't help either.

Comment: can you try to set SPARK_CLASSPATH in all spark-env.sh on all worker nodes and master node?

Comment: SPARK_CLASSPATH is deprecated in Spark 1.0+. I used paramater --jars executing spark-submit script and this helped me ;)

Comment: Can you post your code and the command you use to kick off the job? Are you specifying full or relative paths?

Comment: Try UberJAR or Spark Fat Jar Approach.

Comment: I solved this. You need help, or got the solution ?

Comment: I solved it by using --jars parametr with spark-submit script.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) that will bundle your code and all dependencies in a single JAR that you then submit to Spark.